# bootstrap responsive grid with one item being larger

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ui grid written with css + bootstrap 4 + html, it works but I recently added one element to select an image which is slightly larger. Now the rest of my elements don't fill in the empty space efficiently and responsively. I've been trying to recreate this grid with jsfiddle and placeholder box content, just to focus on the responsiveness of the boxes.

In my current attempts, I'm envisioning something responsive like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|            |  item2  |  item3  |  item4 |
|   large    |         |         |        |
|   item     |-----------------------------
|   content1 |  item5  |         |        |
|            |         |         |        |
-------------------------------------------
```

Mainly trying to fix some edge cases I've been encountering (highlighted in red)
[image]

In my jsfiddle I get close to replicating one situation, but the flex ability for my rows/cols doesn't seem to fill space efficiently:
https://jsfiddle.net/x106mpaw/2/

```css
.settingsCol{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.short{
  max-height:80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<hr><br>
<!---------------   attempt 2    ------------------------------------------------->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col settingsCol col-md-4">
          <!------------------------------ 
          Image Selection Option
          ------------------------------->
          <div class="form-group">
            <span>
              <label for="size">Image:
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-delay="{&quot;show&quot;:&quot;5000&quot;, &quot;hide&quot;:&quot;3000&quot;}" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Chosen image that will be combined with audio to render a video."></i>
              </label>
              
    <div id="upload-3-imgSelect" class="dd-container"><div class="dd-select" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="0"><a class="dd-selected"><img class="dd-selected-image" style='height:22px'src="https://i.imgur.com/MFOH6oD.jpeg"><label class="dd-selected-text">R-11899099-1524358953-8316.jpg</label><small class="dd-selected-description dd-desc dd-selected-description-truncated">1058.1 mb, 600x600</small></a><span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down"></span></div><ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close"><li><a class="dd-option dd-option-selected"> <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="0">  <label class="dd-option-text">R-11899099-1524358953-8316.jpg</label> <small class="dd-option-description dd-desc">1058.1 mb, 600x600</small></a></li></ul></div>
    
            </span>
          </div>      
    </div>
  
      
      <div class="col settingsCol col-md-2 short">
            <!------------------------------ 
              Padding Selection Option
              ------------------------------->
              <div class="form-group">
                <span>
                  <label for="size">Padding:
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="If a padding option is selected, than the image will be padded to reach its resolution."></i>
                  </label>
                  <select id="upload-3-paddingSelect" class="form-control">
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                    <option value="white">White</option>
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
                  </select>
                </span>
              </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col settingsCol col-md-2 short">
              <!------------------------------ 
              Resolution Selection Option
              ------------------------------->
              <div class="form-group">
                <span>
                  <label for="size">Resolution:
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Output resolution for the rendered video."></i>
                  </label>
                  <select id="upload-3-resolutionSelect" class="form-control"><option value="R-11899099-1524358953-8316.jpg" style="width:150px; text-align: left;">600x600 SD</option><option value="R-11899099-1524358953-8316.jpg" style="width:150px; text-align: left;">640x640 SD</option><option value="R-11899099-1524358953-8316.jpg" style="width:150px; text-align: left;">1280x1280 SD</option><option value="R-11899099-1524358953-8316.jpg" style="width:150px; text-align: left;" selected="selected">1920x1920 <a class="red_color">HD</a></option><option value="R-11899099-1524358953-8316.jpg" style="width:150px; text-align: left;">2560x2560 <a class="red_color">HD</a></option></select>
                </span>
              </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      
      <div class="col settingsCol col-md-2 short">
              <!------------------------------ 
              Output Folder Option
              ------------------------------->
              <div class="form-group">
                <span>
                  <label for="size">Output Dir: 
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Output folder where we will render the video."></i>
                  </label>
                  <div id="upload-3-dirText" onclick="changeDir(&quot;upload-3-dirText&quot;, &quot;upload-3&quot;)" class="changeDir">
                    <i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>  CD 2
                  </div>
                </span>
              </div>        
      </div>
      
      <div class="col settingsCol col-md-2 short">
              <!------------------------------ 
              Output Video Format Option [mkv / mp4]
              ------------------------------->
              <div class="form-group">
                <span>
                  <label for="size">Output Vid:
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Choose what file type you want the outputted video(s) to be. Mkv will have higher quality audio."></i>
                  </label>
                  <select id="upload-3-vidFormatSelect" class="form-control">
                    <option value="none">mkv</option>
                    <option value="white">mp4</option>
                  </select>
                </span>
              </div>        
      </div>
      
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me achieve a good, efficiently spaced grid of content cards where one card is larger then the others like in my example picture? Thanks

Comment: Try using a set of the `col-*-*` instead of a simple `col`. So it will be possible to control the behavior of elements when changing the width.

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle code, I tried using col-md-4 and 2 to differentiate between the taller and normal width columns, but Im not getting the best space efficiency yet

Comment: As example: try to write all `col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4` classes at once.